# Can I create an python executable that Trend Micro will not delete?

Tags: python, exe, executable, pyinstaller

I have created a python script to record and append data between spread sheets(.csv and .xlsx). As well as view, watermark, and transfer pictures related to said data.

When I turn it into and executable and run the program the security system on my computer (Trend Micro) sees it as virus/malware and deletes it. The reasoning Trend Micro gives is "Unauthorized File Encryption". On the Trend Micro website there isn't a specific description for this error.

My IT guy put the location of the executable on an exceptions list, which worked for a while, but I want to know if I can make an executable that doesn't have this problem.

The modules I used in the script: Tkinter, tkMessageBox, tkFileDialog, openpyxl, os, pandas, sys, PIL, io, datetime

Also, I am using pyinstaller to create the exe.

Does anyone have experience with this type of issue that could be helpful?

Comment: This question should be directed to the Trend Micro company with the example of the program. Obviously it's their false positive. Or you have a virus.

Comment: This can happen if your antivirus is too strict and doesn't allow execution of any unsigned code or something like that. You can't do much about that (if you can't sign your code with a trusted certificate, of course). Or, you could lower the 'strictness', but this may decrease security.